# Document Template - Columns from Content Type

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, document-template

I have a custom content type that inherits from the document content type, and has 10 columns (single line of text). A document template has been added to the content type from my local documents.

The problem I'm seeing is when I edit the document template, the columns from the content type are not appearing within the Document Information Panel. I have deleted the document template, and readded several times, but I'm still getting the same result.

Are there certain steps that need to be taken to populate the Document Information Panel with the columns from the Content Type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to modify the view and add the columns to the view.  Go to View All Site Content and click the Doument Library and go to Library Settings, scroll to the bottom of the page and click AllItems view which is usually the default view, check the columns to appear on the view and save.